# How to get version info from a shared library into the Android manifest?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-manifest, versioning

We have a shared library that contains version info and is referenced by all our projects in our Visual Studio Solution.

For the most part, we can reference the version string from every project and the dll reflect the info accordingly.

My issue here is, with our Android application (xamarin based). It has a manifest file which contains the versionName and versionCode.

How can we make those values in our android manifest file read from our shared project?

Comment: @Pooya as stated in the question, it is an android project using xamarin and visual studio. and in this instance it DOES have version info - Pooya removed his/her comment, keeping this here for information purposes

Comment: I don't believe there is an API to set these values. You would most likely need to parse your `AndroidManifest.xml` for those specific nodes (`versionName` and `versionCode`) and replace them that way then rebuild. Otherwise it would probably be easiest to just increment manually and rebuild.

Comment: @DustyRoberts You will have to generate Android manifest (or update an existing one) before you build/sign/package as the manifest becomes a `signed` member within the `.apk`. Just unzip a signed `.apk` and you will find a signed manifest that can not be modified as that would invalid the entire package signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that, it is not possible. Because

> The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

From Google's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

So this is a file that is required before the App builds.

C# Code in Shared Project (SAP/PCL) is ready to be used only after successful Compilation. So logically setting the Version Code and Version Name in Android Manifest File from Shared logic is not possible.

Another standard approach would be to set it from String Resource (XML) file in Android. You may have to copy and paste the value from Shared Project to strings.xml file and refer it in manifest, like

```
@string/versionCode
```

Comment: darnit.... lemme see if this can be achieved by creating the manifest file using T4

Comment: Hey @DustyRoberts ... Just outa curiosity, any luck with T4 ?

Comment: i deleted my androidmanifest.xml file and created a t4 template that generates the file. the version is now dynamic :)

Comment: Great :-) I would request you to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I do not know anything about xamarin.

In java you can get the versioninfo from the manifest like this

```
public static String getAppVersionName(final Context context) {
    try {

        final String versionName = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        return versionName;
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I assume that xamarin has some mechanism to call PackageManager to get Packageinfo, too

Comment: I would like to set the values not get them. but thanx for this, i needed this in another project i am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a Dependency Service.  Here's a great article on them: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

The idea would be your Dependency Service would expose the Android specific information to the shared code library.

For instance you might have an interface in your common code declared such as:

```
public interface IPlatformVersionInfo
{
    string GetOSVersion (); 
}
```

Now, in your Android library you would implement it:

```
public class PlatformVersionInfo : IPlatformVersionInfo
{
    public string GetOSVersion () {
        return Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Finally, in your common code you would use your dependency service of choice to invoke an instance of it:

```
var osVersion = DependencyService.Get<IPlatformVersionInfo>().GetOSVersion ();
```

Of course this is somewhat pseudo-code and depending what dependency service you choose the code may look a bit different.

Comment: How does this help? AndroidManifest info is added during compilation. Dependency service only kicks in during run time. Or am I missing something?